# Pandas: unable to save multiple plots using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to save multiple plots created by pandas.dataframe.plot in gif format. I am using a for loop to iterate over the plots. The problem is that the plots that are saved after executing  after executing the loop are not correct. Here is the code

```
for i in range(len(plot_cols)):
    grouped = cust_data[plot_cols[i]].groupby(cust_data['Cluster_ID'])
    mean_trans = grouped.mean()
    plot = mean_trans.plot(kind = 'bar', figsize = [10, 7])
    plot.set_ylabel(plot_cols[i])
    fig = plot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig("C:\\Users\\utkarsh.a.ranjan\\Documents\\pyqt_data\\view_bar_graphs\\cluster_" + str(i))
```

When I remove the for loop and substitute individual values of i, I get the correct plots.

my desired plots are these
[image: here]

the plots I am getting instead are these 
[image: here]

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO please share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can try putting `plt.figure()` at start of the loop for new canvas

Answer (score 0):

clear the plot in each iteration

```
for i in range(len(plot_cols)):
    grouped = cust_data[plot_cols[i]].groupby(cust_data['Cluster_ID'])
    mean_trans = grouped.mean()
    plot = mean_trans.plot(kind = 'bar', figsize = [10, 7])
    plot.set_ylabel(plot_cols[i])
    fig = plot.get_figure()
    ## Clear plot here
    plot.clf()

    fig.savefig("C:\\Users\\utkarsh.a.ranjan\\Documents\\pyqt_data\\view_bar_graphs\\cluster_" + str(i))
```

Comment: why are you clearing before saving?

Comment: the info is already saved in fig variable, info of plot is cleared not of fig

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely answered in the comment (see link to duplicate question), here are some small improvements to your code:

```
import os
def filename(string):
    return os.path.join('C:\\Users\\utkarsh.a.ranjan\\Documents\\'
                        'pyqt_data\\view_bar_graphs',
                        'cluster{}'.format(string))

for i, column in enumerate(plot_cols): 
    mean_trans = (cust_data[column]
                  .groupby(cust_data['Cluster_ID'])
                  .mean())
    ax = mean_trans.plot(kind = 'bar', figsize = [10, 7])
    ax.set_ylabel(plot_cols[i])
    fig = ax.get_figure()        
    fig.savefig(filename(i))
    # initial problem
    ax.clf()
```